# R Selecting Vector Elements Syntax Utilizing dplyr

Tags: r, syntax, dplyr

The following code computes standard deviation across rows for the iris dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% mutate(stDev = apply(.[(1:4)], 1, sd))
```

I cannot wrap my head around the column selection syntax in this code above. Learning R I thought column selection worked in the following manner:

```
library(dplyr)
iris[, 1:4]
```

What's with the `'.'` in the first code block? Are there any other basic examples of column selection using this type of syntax? I understand that the %>% pipe assumes the iris data set for all commands after the pipe. But why does the syntax change?

The column selection `[(1:4)]` in the first code block is missing the `','` and is wrapped in parenthesis `()` instead of square brackets `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `iris[1:4]` and `iris[,1:4]` are valid ways to subset columns. For example:

```
> iris[1:4] %>% head()
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4

> iris[,1:4] %>% head()
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

`()` doesn't do anything in this case. The `.` in `apply(.[(1:4)], 1, sd)` is just a piping syntax that says "put whatever the output from before the pipe to this location". So in this case, `iris` is piped to both the first argument of `mutate` (the default), *and* to `.[(1:4)]`, which evaluates to `iris[(1:4)]`. The following gives the same output:

```
> iris %>% mutate(stDev = apply(.[1:4], 1, sd)) %>% head
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    stDev
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.179449
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.036950
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 1.997498
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 1.912241
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.156386
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2.230844

> iris %>% mutate(stDev = apply(iris[1:4], 1, sd)) %>% head
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    stDev
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.179449
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.036950
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 1.997498
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 1.912241
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.156386
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2.230844
```